# C# Interop GetNamedPipeClientProcessId ERROR_NOT_FOUND 1168 (0x490)

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, interop, named-pipes

I cannot figure out why I am getting an `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` / 1168 (0x490) error code.  If I replace `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` with `GetNamedPipeServerProcessId`, I successfully get the server's process ID.

Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(IntPtr Pipe, out int ClientProcessId);

int GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer)
{
   var hPipe = pipeServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

    if (GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(hPipe, out var clientProcessId))
    {
        return clientProcessId;
    }
    else
    {
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: since `GetNamedPipeServerProcessId()` works, are you calling this code on the client side of the pipe? Does it make sense to call `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId()` on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` after the Client has called the [`CallNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-callnamedpipea) or [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) to connect to the Name Pipe. If the client haven't connect to the Name Pipe, The `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` will failed with `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`(0x490).